# ¿Cómo cerrar instancia de Excel en VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, excel, interop

Que tal amigos, tengo una aplicación de escritorio en la cual abro un archivo en Excel pero cuando cierro la aplicación las instancias aún sigues abiertas.

El archivo Excel lo abro de la siguiente manera:

```
        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Ruta)
        xlApp.Interactive = True
        xlApp.Visible = False
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Y he intentado cerrarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
            xlBook.Close()
            xlApp.Quit()
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheet)
            xlSheet = Nothing
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlBook)
            xlBook = Nothing
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
            xlApp = Nothing            
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

La instancia sigue abierta, ¿Cómo puedo cerrarla?

Answer (score 2):

Se me presentó el mismo problema y buscando, encontré lo siguiente

#### **Causa**

Cuando Visual Studio .NET llama a un objeto COM desde código administrado, se crea automáticamente un Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW). El RCW calcula referencias de llamadas entre la aplicación de .NET y el objeto COM. El RCW mantiene un recuento de referencia en el objeto COM. Por lo tanto, si no se liberan todas las referencias en el RCW, el objeto COM no se cierra.

#### **Solución**

Para asegurarse de que se cierra la aplicación de Office, asegúrese de que el código de automatización cumple los criterios siguientes:
Declare cada objeto como una nueva variable. Por ejemplo, cambie la siguiente línea de código

```
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add()
```

a la siguiente:

```
dim oBooks as Excel.WorkbooksoBooks = oExcel.Workbooks
oBook = oBooks.Add()
```

En resumen, cuando utilizas un objeto, eso genera una instancia de dicha clase, que debe eliminarse explicitamente, aun cuando haya sido instanciada de forma implicita, en el artículo detallan las formas de eliminar estas instancias.

Fuente: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/317109/office-application-does-not-quit-after-automation-from-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

También debes liberar la aplicación `xlApp.Quit()`  y recomendaría ademas: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);`  para liberar xlApp, xlBook y si instancias una hoja... también.

Comment: Que tal @German AT, así lo tengo como me indicas pero no se cierran las instancias.

Comment: liberar los 3 objetos también? `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlBook);System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheet);` ?

Comment: Así es, lo hago de la siguiente manera: 

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheet) xlSheet = Nothing System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlBook) xlBook = Nothing System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp) xlApp = Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

Aparte de hacer lo que te comenta @German anade:

```
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Rafa, todas las aportaciones constructivas son bienvenidas. No obstante, para que tu respuesta pueda ser de mayor utilidad a otros usuarios y evitar un posible cierre de la misma por baja calidad sería muy oportuno que la ampliases con algo de información sobre lo que hace tu código y porqué debe añadirlo. Saludos.