# Problema con la liberia de Word Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

Tags: c#, librería

Tengo una función en mi código c# que me permite imprimir un archivo de word en el cual reemplazo campos para generar recibos.

El problema es que al reiniciar o iniciar mi PC de manera normal, se me ejecutan  cientos y cientos de hojas de word en blanco.

¿saben a qué se debe o qué puedo hacer para controlarlo?.

Enseguida les dejo mis funciones.

```
private void FindReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp, object findText, object replaceWithText)
{
    object matchCase = false;
    object matchWholeWord = true;
    object matchWildCards = false;
    object matchSoundLike = false;
    object nmatchAllForms = false;
    object forward = true;
    object format = false;
    object matchKashida = false;
    object matchDiactitics = false;
    object matchAlefHamza = false;
    object matchControl = false;
    object read_only = false;
    object visible = true;
    object replace = 2;
    object wrap = 1;

    WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord, ref matchWildCards,
        ref matchSoundLike, ref nmatchAllForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
        ref matchKashida, ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
}

public void CreateWordDocument(object saveAs)
{
    object missing = Missing.Value;

    try
    {
        var nombres = (from emp in entityRef.empleados
                       join mr in entityRef.ca_prestamos_ahorros on emp.idEmpleado equals mr.idempleado
                       join empr in entityRef.empresas on emp.idEmpresa equals empr.idempresas
                       where emp.idEmpleado == PrincipalModel.PrincipalModelRef.ID
                       select new
                       {
                           NombreEmpleado = emp.nombre + " " + emp.aPaterno + " " + emp.aMaterno,

                       }).FirstOrDefault();

            WordRuta = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\fgv.docx";
            Word.Document aDoc = null; //esta limpiando la variable-
            if (System.IO.File.Exists((string)WordRuta))
            {
              NombreEmpleado = nombres.NombreEmpleado;
              DateTime hoy = (DateTime)FechaAbono;

              dia = hoy.ToString("dd");
              mes = hoy.ToString("MMMM");
              año = hoy.ToString("yyyy");

              object readOnly = true;
              object invisible = true;
              WordApp.Visible = true;

            aDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(WordRuta, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                                    aDoc.Activate();

                    FindReplace(WordApp, "<nopag>", NumePago);
                    FindReplace(WordApp, "<abono>", ImporteAbono);
                    FindReplace(WordApp, "<dia>", dia);
                    FindReplace(WordApp, "<mes>", mes);
                    FindReplace(WordApp, "<año>", año);
                    FindReplace(WordApp, "<nombre empleado>", NombreEmpleado);

            }
            else
            {
               MessageBox.Show("El archivo no existe");
                return;
            }

        aDoc.SaveAs2(ref saveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);  

                      MessageBox.Show("Recibo creado...");


    }

    catch (Exception r)

    {

        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("ERROR AL INTENTAR CREAR EL RECIBO");
    }

}
```

Comment: de donde sale la variable `WordApp` ?

Comment: no entiendo la relacion entre reiniciar la pc con ver hojas de word, acaso esta app que desarrollas la pusiste en el inicio de windows ?

Comment: Word.Application WordApp = new Word.Application();  es una variable de la lireria que instancio. La aplicación no esta en el inicio de windows, por eso entiendo porque se ejecuta, este problema comenzó desde que empecé a hacer uso de la liberia, quisiera saber como evitar que se ejecuten las hojas de word si es que es por causa del uso de la libreria

Comment: Usar las Api COM de Word la verdad son un dolor de cabeza, por eso recomiendo usar unas basadas en open xml. El que inicie instancias cuando reinicias la verdad ni idea, revisa si la app no se establecio en el inicio de windows. El uso de la libreria no causa este problema que mencionas, si puede quedar la instancia activa, pero tienes que ser solo una cuando cada vez que ejecutas la aplicacion.

Answer (score 1):

Las `API COM de Word` tienen un problema para liberar la instancia correctamente, dejando esta como un proceso activo a pesar que tu aplicacion ya no este ejecutando.

[¿Cómo cerrar instancia de Excel en VB.Net?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70906/c%C3%B3mo-cerrar-instancia-de-excel-en-vb-net)

Nota: lo planteado en la ultima respuesta, si se que el link esta en vb.net, pero la idea aplica en c#

La idea es aplicar `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` para que el objeto `COM` se liberado correctamente

[Office application does not exit after automation from Visual Studio .NET client](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/317109/office-application-does-not-exit-after-automation-from-visual-studio-n)

Tambien tienes que aplicar el

```
WordApp.Quit();
```

para que se cierre la instancia, esto no veo que lo estas aplicando en el codigo que publicaste

Comment: No tenia idea del uso del WordApp.Quit(); iré a aplicar lo que comentan y regreso, gracias